# How to count unique values of unique values in a table

Tags: bash, awk, sed, uniq

Still a beginner here.

How do I count the unique values of a unique set of other values in a table using bash awk sed etc? 
So in a two (or more) column table such as this:

```
AA a
AA b
AA c
AA a
AB b
AA a
AB c
AA a
AC b
AC b
XX z
```

how would I get an output of

```
AA 3
AB 2
AC 1
XX 1
```

Where the second column of the output is the count of unique values of all the possible first column values;

So , there are 6 AAs but only 3 unique AA values etc.

I don't want to use SQL. just bash command line programs such as awk... any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++{u[$1]++}END{for (k in u) print k,u[k]}' file
AA 3
AB 2
AC 1
XX 1
```

To ensure sorted output pipe to `sort -rnk2` for a reverse numerical sort on the second field:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++{u[$1]++}END{for (k in u) print k,u[k]}' file | sort -rnk2
AA 3
AB 2
XX 1
AC 1
```

**Explanation:**

We keep a count of all the unique lines in the associative array `a` and only update the secondary array `u` if we haven't seen the current line before.

Comment: Well done! Why trying to figure out some awk code when sudo_O is online? :D

Comment: Thank you :) Partially correct this only works for tables of only two columns to work on a table of multiple columns (where the columns of interest were the first 2) I did: awk '{print $1FS$2}' file.txt |awk '!a[$0]++{u[$1]++}END{for (k in u) print k,u[k]}'    Is there a more concise way ?  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking if it is possible in other ways, here is a  non `awk` solution:

```
sort file | uniq | cut -f1 -d' ' | uniq -c | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sort -u file | uniq -cw2 | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Comment: Note this is a fixed width solution on the first two characters on the line.